# Pandas: change value based on multiple conditions of different type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make a Champions League Fantasy statistic table, and I'm getting data from 2 different sites that name the player slightly different between each other.

I have `df1` from site 1:

```
                name     age       team skill  cost  gls  ast
0       Lionel Messi  34-175      Paris     4  11.3    5    0
1   Ryan Gravenberch  19-214       Ajax     3   6.2    0    0
2     Junior Messias  30-217      Milan     3   6.5    1    0
3  Kepa Arrizabalaga  27-074    Chelsea     1   5.0    0    0
4     Kenneth Taylor  19-214       Ajax     3   5.0    0    0
5            Alisson  30-320  Liverpool     1   6.1    0    0
```

And `df2` from site 2:

```
      name     age       team  gls  ast
0     Kepa  27-074    Chelsea    0    0
1   Lionel  34-175      Paris    5    0
2   Junior  30-217      Milan    1    0
3  Kenneth  19-214       Ajax    0    0
4   Neymar  29-314      Paris    0    0
5     Ryan  19-214       Ajax    0    0
```

My goal is to match the names based on multiple conditions:

- Age (string in `df2` **equal** to string in `df1`)
- Team (string in `df2` **equal** to string in `df1`)
- Name (string in `df2` **is contained** in string in `df1`)

The reason I want to pass the name as last condition is because there are cases were two players were born the exact same day and play for the same team like Kenneth Taylor and Ryan Gravenberch

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
df2.loc[(df2['team'] == df1['team']) & (df2['age'] == df1['age']) & (df2['name'].str.contains(df1['name'].str)), 'name'] = df1['name']
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

The desire output for `df2` is:

```
                name     age     team  gls  ast
0  Kepa Arrizabalaga  27-074  Chelsea    0    0
1       Lionel Messi  34-175    Paris    5    0
2     Junior Messias  30-217    Milan    1    0
3     Kenneth Taylor  19-214     Ajax    0    0
4             Neymar  29-314    Paris    0    0
5   Ryan Gravenberch  19-214     Ajax    0    0
```

Where all the names from `df2` that matched the conditions were replaced with the names from `df1`

Comment: Shouldn't `Kepa` in the desired output be `Kepa Arrizabalaga`?

Comment: No, because I want all the names like in df1

Comment: But the string in df2 is not strictly contained in df1 as per the mentioned matching rules. Unless you mean to check if the shorter of the two strings is contained in the other?

Comment: in any case I've modified my answer to consider both cases, do see if it works for you

Comment: I am getting a different error with your code. "TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern"

Comment: str.contains() method takes a string, but you are giving a string object with multiple strings in it.

Comment: And is there a way to solve it?

Comment: @IvánDíazdeLeón : Could you try my solution once and see if it produces the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `merge`:

```
matches = df2.merge(df1[["name", "age", "team"]],
                    on=["age", "team"],
                    how="left")
matches["name_y"] = matches["name_y"].fillna(matches["name_x"])
matches = matches.where(matches.apply(lambda x: x["name_x"] in x["name_y"], axis=1)).dropna()
output = matches.drop("name_x", axis=1).rename(columns={"name_y": "name"}).reindex(df2.columns, axis=1)

>>> output
                 name     age     team  gls  ast
0  Kepa Arrizabalaga  27-074  Chelsea  0.0  0.0
1       Lionel Messi  34-175    Paris  5.0  0.0
2     Junior Messias  30-217    Milan  1.0  0.0
4     Kenneth Taylor  19-214     Ajax  0.0  0.0
5             Neymar  29-314    Paris  0.0  0.0
6   Ryan Gravenberch  19-214     Ajax  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing here is that the reason I want to check if name in df2 is contained in df1 is because there's a chance where two players share birthday and team, so I would pass their name as a last filter, and with your solution, that problem still remains

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. I edited to include a `fillna` but if that doesn't work, you should update your question to include the edge cases.

Comment: I updated my question, in case you come up with some solution :)

Comment: @IvánDíazdeLeón - Edited!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the answer you desire. There is no need of separate condition again based on name.

```
df2.loc[(df2['team'] == df1['team']) & (df2['gls'] == df1['gls']), 'name'] = df1['name']
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is a problem, there are two players from Ajax that have exactly the same age, I will update my question to make it clear, thanks for your answer

Comment: I already edited the question to make it as clear as possible :)